# .htaccess not working on SSL apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

Trying to fix this .htaccess, so it can work on a SSL apache server. Before it was hosted on another Linux server (http://) and was working without problems, but when uploading the files to another Linux server with apache and SSL (https://), it stopped working. The main function is to hide the .php extension...

Here´s what I was using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does anything in the .htaccess work at all on the new server?

Comment: @BrianGottier , how can I tell? The main function I'm looking for is not working... Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Try rewriting to a file that doesn't exist and see if it throws an error.

Comment: @BrianGottier, didn't understand that... What should I rewrite, the code inside, the file extension? Example?

Comment: I provided an answer, although technically it's not really a good answer, but hopefully helps you on your way.

Comment: cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
 sudo vim default-ssl
Change AllowOverride None to All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, .htaccess files may not be allowed, and by default on many systems they are not allowed. To see if .htaccess is allowed, make this your .htaccess:

```
BREAK IT!
```

That should be the only contents in your .htaccess. Attempt to load any page on your website, and if .htaccess usage is enabled, you would see "Internal Server Error" or possibly some other error, but you would not see your actual page.

If you do see the error, that's actually good and means .htaccess usage is enabled. If you don't see the error, it's likely that you will have to find your Apache .conf file and inside look for the line(s):

```
AllowOverride None
```

Change that to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

If after doing that you still can't use .htaccess, then there may be other apache related files that have "AllowOverride None". On that comes to mind is your virtual host file, and on my system that is located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

If you still have problems, check this out:
https://docs.bolt.cm/3.3/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works

Comment: Excellent! I'll try that out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm interested to hear what happens, so please come back and report.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep you informed about this. It seems that Apache is not active on the server, need to check some things. I'm just passing the file to someone who uploads it, that why it's a little slow to get answers (can't get access to server). What would be another solution if apache is not active?

Comment: Just check out that link in my answer. Apache must be active, unless this is nginx or some other type of webserver. Are you sure it's apache?

Comment: Exactly, it´s on **nginx** :( , Brian... What could I do there, to have that htaccess function to hide the file extensions?

Comment: Try the converter here: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Comment: Seems that it's working now. I'll post you back when I get the solution from the other side. I think they used another script... Thanks for the help Brian!

Comment: For the future, you might try to find out the server details as your starting the project, because you can usually set up a virtual machine that matches the production environment, and not have surprises like this. Check out Virtualbox. It's free.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I always get access to servers and FTP, but this time it was just web development and giving the files to the person in charge of uploading the them. I asked for some info, but didn't expect this server really... I'll be careful next time, thanks for the advice, bruh!

Comment: Hey, Brian... THey made some changes con the configuration file, so it could read the initial .htaccess I had... Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Yes, i knew my htaccess file ignored when accessing the site with https  but don't know how to make it work... the default-ssl.conf doesn't have any setting like allow override option, so manually added it inside directory tag and its now working

Answer (score 1):

Solution is for the issue, need to change in apache2.conf file after that it will works,

Change this file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
update it same

OLD:
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

New Updated Code:
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Apache 2.4.23 with .htaccess error 404 set up. 
Using it with HTTP works fine; access it with HTTPS didn't work.
I seted AllowOverride All in the http.conf and error 404 wors well.