# HTTPS can't read htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, yii2-advanced-app

I created an HTTPS server with openSSL on my local server where there is an htaccess file, but the htaccess file can't run properly. is there something wrong with the configuration?
here SSL configuration :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sylla

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/2018/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/2018/server.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

[.htaccess configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgISy.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWqXl.png)

for your info, i created project using Yii 2 (advance) and i want to remove /frontend/web on URL. thx

Comment: Closed, Read This :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124884/htaccess-not-working-on-ssl-apache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess not working on SSL apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124884/htaccess-not-working-on-ssl-apache)